# GCP Automation with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-gcp

I am using GCP to host my website. Now I have a scenario where I want a user to register themselves on my website and when I approve their request I want my backend application Java (Spring Boot) to create a database, subdomain, Load Balancer and storage for that particular user. Please assist me in doing this.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I am currently looking for different spring gcp libraries but I didn't find any thing that can help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Other than creating a database when executing DDL, Spring Cloud GCP does not provide any shortcuts for the admin tasks you need. You would instead be using the Java client libraries for each product directly.

Comment: Can you please point me some java libraries that will help me in completing the task

Comment: [Compute Engine client library](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries) for the load balancers (you will likely want the `BackendServicesClient`); [GCS for storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries); database will depend on the specific engine -- there is Cloud SQL (MySQL/Postgres), Spanner, and no-SQL Datastore/Firestore.